# The sign of the lobes in an atomic orbital

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

In atomic orbital diagram of an atomic orbital, the lobes are represented as either positive or negative. It is said that the wave function is 'positive' where the lobe is depicted positive and 'negative' where it is depicted negative. But what I am confused about is that when electrons are paired in an atomic orbital, is one the electrons in the positive region and the other in the negative? And if this is the case, what is the exact configuration of the electron pair in the 1s orbital where there isn't a negative lobe? And what about the case where there are multiple positive and negative lobes like the d-orbitals, do the 'positive electrons' move between the two positive lobes and vice versa for 'negative electron'?

[image: The red regions are positive whereas the blue are negative.]

Forgive me for my poor terminology as I am not used to treating electrons as waves and I do not know the mathematics of the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: The sign of the wave function has no relation to the probable location of a particular electron in the orbital.